# How can I assign a Dictionary to a combobox's Items (Display and Value Members)?

Tags: c#, dictionary, combobox

I know how to assign values from a query to a ListBox's Display and Value members:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.CPSConnStr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.SelectUnitsQuery, con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            ((ListBox)checkedListBoxUnits).DataSource = dt;
            ((ListBox)checkedListBoxUnits).DisplayMember = "Unit";
            ((ListBox)checkedListBoxUnits).ValueMember = "Unit";
        }
    }
}
```

...and how to assign a single value to a ComboBox like so:

```
List<String> schedulableWeeks = PlatypusUtils.GetWeekBeginnings(WEEKS_COUNT).ToList();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = schedulableWeeks;
comboBoxWeekToSchedule.DataSource = bs;
```

...but how can I assign a Dictionary to a combo box, with the string value of my Dictionary as the Display value, and the DateTime as the ValueMember? I tried this:

```
Dictionary<String, DateTime> schedulableWeeks = 
    PlatypusUtils.GetWeekBeginningsDict(WEEKS_TO_OFFER_COUNT);
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = schedulableWeeks;
comboBoxWeekToSchedule.DataSource = bs;
comboBoxWeekToSchedule.DisplayMember = schedulableWeeks[0];
comboBoxWeekToSchedule.ValueMember = schedulableWeeks[1];
```

...thinking that I could access the string via Dictionary element 0, and the DateTime via element 1, but it doesn't even compile ("Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'") - the same err msg for both lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting key and value for combobox as below:

```
comboBoxWeekToSchedule.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBoxWeekToSchedule.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `toDictionary()`? I am not sure what PlatypusUtils.GetWeekBeginningsDict exactly returns, but I'm guessing this could solve the issue.

```
Dictionary<String, DateTime> schedulableWeeks = PlatypusUtils.GetWeekBeginningsDict(WEEKS_TO_OFFER_COUNT).ToDictionary(x => x.Key);
```

Might also be a bindingsource issue with KeyValuePair:

```
comboBoxWeekToSchedule.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBoxWeekToSchedule.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Comment: There's no .ToDict(); there is a ToDictionary(), but it requires args, and I don't know which args to give it.

Comment: ToDictionary(x => x.Key)? Something like this. Check out [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = schedulableWeeks;
comboBoxWeekToSchedule.DataSource = bs;
comboBoxWeekToSchedule.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBoxWeekToSchedule.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Basically, each item in the dictionary has a "Key" and a "Value" because each item in the dictionary is a `KeyValuePair<string,DateTime>`